# How can I hide suggestions and make them appear when I write?

Tags: html, css, search-box

```css
body {
  
  background-image: url("pirat.jpg");

}


h1{
    font-size :100px;
}


h3{
    font-size :50px;
    
}

<style type="text">
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
outline: none;
}
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}
.container{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
.container nav{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
height: 60px;
background-color: #383838;
color: white;
}

nav ul{
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 600px;
}
nav li{
display: inline-block;
line-height: 56px;
margin:0 25px;
}
nav li a{
display: block;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
transition: .5s all;
}
a:hover{
color:#808080;
border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
#myInput{
position: relative;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 20px;
width: 2300x;
height: 25px;
border-bottom: 2px solid#006699;
font-size: 15px;
color: #006699;
border-radius: 50px;
align-items: center;
float: right;
z-index: 0;
}


#btn{
display: none;

}
.check{
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
float: right;
line-height: 60px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
nav ul{
position: fixed;
width: 40%;
height: 100vh;
top: 60px;
left: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #2c3e50;
transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li{
display: block;
}
nav ul li a{
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}
.check{
display: block;
}
#btn:checked ~ ul{
left: 60%;
}

@media(max-width: 500px){

}

#myUL {
  
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd; 
  margin-top: -1px; 
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 18px;   color: black; 
  display: block; 
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}


  .text input:focus + .hide { 
    display: block !important; 
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .container { position: relative; }
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Home</title>
<font color="white">
<center>
<h1></h1>
</center>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Principala.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<font color="white">
<div class="relative">
<font color = "blue">
<h3></h3>

<div class="container">
    <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="btn">
    <label for="btn" class="check">!!!</label>
    <div class="search"><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search engine"></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class=hide>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li></ul></div>

<script src="Principala.js"></script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong? The suggestions don't want to show when I write in the search box

Comment: Hi, it's probably a good idea to have a really close look at your HTML and make sure it is legal and uptodate. You could usefully start by putting it through a validator. Then put the corrected version into your question and include your Javascript as we can't at the moment help further because we don't know what myFunction is trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: It will read more easily if you format the code you insert here.